# How to get admin address while deploying transparent upgradeable proxy from OZ

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts, upgrading

After OZ version 5, the admin contract is deployed from within the constructor of the proxy.

And the admin address is emitted in the events of the deployment transaction. To get the admin address we can check the events in etherscan.

The problem comes in when writing tests in hardhat. How can get the admin address? How can I fetch the event while I deploy the contract using deployProxy method of OZ upgrade pluggin.

```
const Reveal = await ethers.getContractFactory("Reveal");
reveal = await upgrades.deployProxy(Reveal, [allSigners[0].address]);
let receipt = await reveal.deploymentTransaction();
console.log(receipt);
```

Tried this, but the receipt doesn't have any logs.